# read informations from Web Feature Service (WFS) with R

Tags: r, web-services, gis

I like to use a Web Feature Service (WFS) [1] to get soil informations. But I am very unsure how to do it right, maybe you can give me a hint on how to get all available informations.

I can query `bmf:Musterstueck` and convert it to a Simple Feature. But if I do the same with `so:SoilHorizon` or `so:ObservedSoilProfile` I get the error message like

```
Error: Cannot open "https://via.bund.de/bmf/inspire/so/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=so%3ASoilHorizon"; The file doesn't seem to exist.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 1: HTTP error code : 403
```

Thank you
Christof

[1] https://via.bund.de/bmf/inspire/so/wfs?service=wfs&request=getcapabilities

```
                  name                           title
      bmf:Musterstueck Musterstücke der Bodenschätzung
        so:SoilHorizon             INSPIRE SoilHorizon
so:ObservedSoilProfile     INSPIRE ObservedSoilProfile
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(ows4R)
library(httr)

wfs = WFSClient$new("https://via.bund.de/bmf/inspire/so/wfs", "2.0.0", logger = "INFO")
wfs$getFeatureTypes(pretty = TRUE)

url <- parse_url("https://via.bund.de/bmf/inspire/so/wfs")

url$query <- list(service  = "wfs", 
                  version  = "2.0.0", 
                  request  = "GetFeature", 
                  typename = "bmf:Musterstueck")  

request <- build_url(url)
request

bmf_musterstueck <- read_sf(request)
bmf_musterstueck
```

Comment: Why you don't use a GIS like QGIS? Have you tried to query this way?

Comment: A 403 error means you don't have permission to see that data